# I used uialertview in iOS8 , but the application crashed after I clicked the Cancel button twice

Tags: ios, crash, uialertview

I do nothing in the cancel delegate method.
I need help.

My code:

```
- (void)back{
if(_stateView.stateType == StateType_Failed || _stateView.stateType == StateType_WiFi){
    UIAlertView *alertView =  [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"温馨提示" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"您确认要放弃连接 %@ 免费热点",_SSID] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"确定" otherButtonTitles:@"不，谢谢", nil];
    [alertView show];
    return;
}
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if(buttonIndex == 0){
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

}

I added a breakpoint and got the crash log and stacks.

```
[_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow becomeFirstResponder]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15e752ec0

(lldb) bt

* thread #1: tid = 0x1c8de, 0x000000018359017c CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 968, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18359017c)
  * frame #0: 0x000000018359017c CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 968
    frame #1: 0x0000000183492ccc CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    frame #2: 0x00000001880ac704 UIKit`-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _restoreInputViewsWithId:animated:] + 356
    frame #3: 0x00000001883ac834 UIKit`-[UIAlertController _restoreInputViewsAnimated:] + 128
    frame #4: 0x00000001883ac5e0 UIKit`-[UIAlertController viewDidDisappear:] + 92
    frame #5: 0x0000000187fe3f28 UIKit`-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 440
    frame #6: 0x0000000187fe452c UIKit`-[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 344
    frame #7: 0x00000001882d2b58 UIKit`-[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 984
    frame #8: 0x00000001882d512c UIKit`__56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 168
    frame #9: 0x00000001880eefd0 UIKit`-[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 132
    frame #10: 0x0000000188004774 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 408
```

......
(the code is too much,I can not post them all.)

Comment: Please post your code here, displaying alertview and clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex method

Comment: How are you able to click the CancelButton Twice, on first click itself alertView should be dismissed.

Comment: Yes,actually I clicked the first ，it dismissed.  And then I clicked the back button, it showed. so I can click it the Twice, then it crashed.

Comment: But it should have popped your ViewController in this case. Right? or what is the functionality.

Comment: sorry,I describe a little bit wrong. The pop method didn't worked when I clicked every time, because it will return like this:                                       [alertView show];
return;

Comment: then probably dont return use if else condition and in else use the popViewControllerAnimated of back method.

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception breakpoint on the throw and try to reproduce it while debugging. And post some code here, so to let us see what's wrong...

It seems that your UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow has been deallocated too early...

Comment: I did it ,so I could got this logs,and I'd posted my code,thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are popping your viewcontroller before the alert is displayed.

Remove the `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` from the `-(void)back` method

For clarity. Your code should be:

```
-(void)back
{
     if(_stateView.stateType == StateType_Failed || _stateView.stateType == StateType_WiFi)
    { 
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"温馨提示" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"您确认要放弃连接 %@ 免费热点",_SSID] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"确定" otherButtonTitles:@"不，谢谢", nil];
    [alertView show]; 
    return; 
    } 
    }

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
if(buttonIndex == 0)
{ 
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
} 
}
```

Comment: Don't thing so this will work as already in if condition return is there which will not let the control pass to popViewControllerAnimated when AlertView is displayed.